# Callback an unknown class+function

Tags: c++

My C++ is rusty. I'd like MyClass to know nothing about Foo and have a callback to run a function in foo. I don't know how to define callback_pair or how to call SetCallback

```
class MyClass{
    tuple<cb, ptr> callback_pair

    int run() { 
        auto that=callback_pair<1>();
        auto cb = callback_pair<0>(); 
        int a=1, b=2, c=3;
        auto result = cb(that, a, b, c); //this calls foo.the_function
        return result;
    }
    void SetCallback(tuple<cb, ptr> cb) { callback_pair=cb; )
};

class Foo {
    int d;
    int the_func(int a, b, c) {
        return a+b+c+d
    }
}
//myclass.SetCallback(what_do_I_write_here)
```

Comment: I created a workaround by creating a virtual class. MyClass knows about it, Foo implements it. But I'd like an answer closer to what I asked

Comment: We have `std::function` and `std::bind` now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `MyClass` must know *something* about `Foo`, namely the signature of whatever method you plan on using as a callback; otherwise, how would it know what to pass in as parameters, or what type to expect to get as output? If the callback signature is known and fixed, for instance `int(int,int,int)` as you have above, you could use a construction like this:

```
class MyClass {
    std::function<int(int,int,int)> callback;

public:
    int run() {
        return callback(1,2,3); // or whatever
    }

    template <typename Class>
    void SetCallback (Class& o, int (Class::*m) (int,int,int)) {
        callback = [&o,m] (int a, int b, int c) { return (o.*m)(a,b,c); };
    }

    template <typename Class>
    void SetCallback (Class const& o, int (Class::*m) (int,int,int) const) {
        callback = [&o,m] (int a, int b, int c) { return (o.*m)(a,b,c); };
    }
};
```

The above implementation of `MyClass` works as follows: `callback` is a function object, initially undefined, which takes three `int`s and returns an `int`. `SetCallback` takes two parameters: An object `o` on which the callback should be performed and a method `m` on that object which conforms to the signature of `callback`. It doesn't care what the type of `o` is; thanks to type-erasure, `MyClass` never needs to know what it's actually calling.

Take special notice of the two versions of `SetCallback` -- one each for `const` and non-`const` objects. In reality, you should be writing overloads for `volatile` and `const volatile` as well, but those are comparatively much rarer than `const`. In the future, once exception specifications and transactions become part of the type system, we will also have to care about `noexcept` and synchronization, and the resulting combinatoric explosion of types will be difficult to deal with effectively without some very clever language support. But this example shows you how that sort of code would be written, and it's probably good enough for your purposes.

The implementation looks ugly, but it actually provides a very clean interface; given `Foo` as you've written above, you would use `MyClass`'s callback functionality like this:

```
MyClass test;
Foo foo;

foo.d = 4;
test.SetCallback (foo, &Foo::the_func);
int result = test.run(); // result = 10
```

The above code will work with any type that has a method with the signature `int(int,int,int)`. Note that you must call `SetCallback` before you call `run`, or else you'll get a `std::bad_function_call` exception because the callback hasn't been defined yet.